# Winforms c# Changing background Image of Parent form from popup form

Tags: c#, winforms, popup, background-image, mdiparent

I have two forms a & b. Form a is main form and on one of its button click event form b is shown as a small window. On the popup (form b), I have an option to select image. What I need to do is when I click on save button of popup (form b), form a (main form's) background image should be set to image selected via popup form (b).

I have tried following code but this.Parent, this.Owner all is returning null for popup form (b). I have specified form a as MDI.

```
this.Owner.BackgroundImage = pictureBoxBackground.Image;
this.Parent.BackgroundImage = pictureBoxBackground.Image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have a public Image property like so inside Form b:

```
private Image image;
public Image SelectedImage
{
    get
    {
        return image;
    }
}
```

And then I would add a button_Click event (or whatever you use to confirm selection). This event would close the form and set the return image.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = [Whatever Image variable that you want to return];
    Close();
}
```

Making FormB look like this.

```
public class FormB : Form
{
    //[...]Stuff
    private Image image;
    public Image SelectedImage
    {
        get
        {
            return image;
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        image = [Whatever Image variable that you want to return];
        Close();
    }
}
```

And finally, to use this for the background image of FormA. Simply have the following procedure.

```
public void ChangeBackground()
{
    FormB b = new FormB();
    b.ShowDialog();
    this.BackgroundImage = b.SelectedImage;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, but OP didn't say specifically the form B is opened as a modal dialog, and also that the button should close the form. And even if that is the case, the good practice requires checking the `ShowDialog` result for Ok before performing some post actions.

Comment: I know, I just thought I'd leave room for ambiguity because the person didn't leave much detail on their specific code and use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the popup to pop up as a dialog and return the image you can place the image in a property. Example:

```
public class Parent : Form
{
     var popup = new Popup();
     var result = popup.ShowDialog();
     if(result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        this.BackgroundImage = popup.Image;
     }
}

public class Popup : Form
{
    private void SelectImage()
    {
        Image = pictureBoxBackground.Image;
    }

    public string Image {get;set;}
}
```

If you'd rather have the popup open as a regular window and be able to use the parent meanwhile, you need to use events, more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Parent : Form
{
     var popup = new Popup();
     popup.BackgroundImageChanged += (sender, args) => this.BackgroundImage = args.Image;
     //...
}

public class Popup : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<ImageChangedEventArgs> BackgroundImageChanged;

    private void SelectImage()
    {
        // ...
        OnBackgroundImageChanged(pictureBoxBackground.Image);
    }

    private void OnBackgroundImageChanged(string image)
    {
        if(BackgroundImageChanged != null)
        {
            var e = new ImageChangedEventArgs(image);
            BackgroundImageChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class ImageChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ImageChangedEventArgs(string image)   
    {
        Image = image;
    }
    public string Image { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Suspiciously similar to mine, hmmm.

Comment: Haha, yeah it is the obvious way to do it assuming the form is a modal :) Wasnt quite quick enough

Comment: Thanks @Rariolu & frich, that did the trick. I can mark only one as answer so marking the one which came first :)